# MySQL Stored Procedure Code — "No Parameter Named 'CustomerID'"

Tags: java, mysql

I'm creating a customer information form in NetBeans which will insert rows into my `customers` table in the database I've created in MySQL.

Couple questions: Did I use the INSERT statement correctly in the stored procedure SQL code?

Am I correctly listing the parameter names in the stored procedure for the callableStatement?

The error message after inputting values into the text fields on NetBeans GUI: `Error while performing insert - No parameter named 'CustomerID.'`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InputValues(IN CustomerID int(3), IN LastName varchar(30), IN FirstName varchar(30), IN EmailAddress varchar(30), IN Address varchar(30), IN City varchar(30), IN State varchar(30), IN ZIP varchar(5), IN Phone varchar(12))
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CustomerID, LastName, FirstName, EmailAddress, Address, City, State, ZIP, Phone)
    VALUES (CustomerID, LastName, FirstName, EmailAddress, Address, City, State, ZIP, Phone);
    SELECT CustomerID, LastName, FirstName, EmailAddress, Address, City, State, ZIP, Phone FROM CUSTOMER;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

```
try {
    // TODO: Set up the SQL statement to call the stored procedure.
    String insertStoreProc = "{call InputValues(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}";
    callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(insertStoreProc);

    // TODO: Provide values to the parameters.
    callableStatement.setInt("CustomerID", CustomerID);
    callableStatement.setString("LastName", LastName);
    callableStatement.setString("FirstName", FirstName);
    callableStatement.setString("EmailAddress", EmailAddress);
    callableStatement.setString("Address", Address);
    callableStatement.setString("City", City);
    callableStatement.setString("State", State);
    callableStatement.setString("ZIP", ZIP);
    callableStatement.setString("Phone", Phone);
    // TODO: Repeat for each of the other parameters (all String).

    int records = callableStatement.executeUpdate();

    if (records == 1) {
        showAlert("Database Success",
                "Success while performing insert",
                e.getMessage(),
                AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        // TODO: Display alert message about successful insert.
    } else {
        showAlert("Database Error",
                "Error while performing insert",
                e.getMessage(),
                AlertType.ERROR);// TODO: Display alert message indicating record was not inserted.
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    showAlert("Database Error",
            "Error while performing insert",
            e.getMessage(),
            AlertType.ERROR);
    return;
} finally {
    if (callableStatement != null) {
        callableStatement.close();
    }

    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Expected data to input into the values in the customer table. Instead seeing `Error while performing insert No parameter named 'CustomerID.'`

Answer (score 0):

When you use ? you don't use named parameters, you use index number starting from 1.. i.e. instead of:

```
callableStatement.setInt("CustomerID", CustomerID);
```

You use:

```
callableStatement.setInt(1, CustomerID);
```